# Set a javascript breakpoint in code - in chrome - how to know where the debugger was 1 step before?

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, debugging, breakpoints

I put a breakpoint right at the beginning of the javascript function, the execution code paused in the debugger.
Based on that, how to find the place where the debugger jumped into that function, i.e. the previous line in the javascript file.
By clicking on F10 or F11 buttons, I go next. How to step back to set up a breakpoint one step earlier?

Thank you.

Comment: Umm, read the docs for Chrome devtools?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the [Call Stack](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#call-stack-panel). There, you can see which function calls led to your breakpoint.